# Why window shows style at design time and not at run time

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, styles

I created brand new wpf application and on the MainWindow.xaml I have:
[image]

**why is it that when I run that application I don't see the same font?** The xaml code I have is:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" >
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial Black"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>This is a TextBlock</TextBlock>
    <Label>This is a Label</Label>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known issue, you may need to set explicit style on window.

define the style in application resources or perhaps merge the same using a resource dictionary

eg

```
<Style x:Key="myWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}" >
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial Black"/>
</Style>
```

use the same as

```
<Window Style="{StaticResource myWindowStyle}" ... />
```

---

if you just want to unify the font in the app then perhaps use [TextElement.FontFamily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.fontfamily(v=vs.110).aspx)

sample

```
<Window TextElement.FontFamily="Arial Black" ... />
```

this will help you apply the same font on all the child elements unless explicitly specified.